# How to use elasticsearch autocomplete with multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, search, autocomplete, autosuggest

I use ElasticSearch 6.8.8. I have 2 fields for suggest, its the key and value field, and using autocomplete type. So my question is, how to search first by key and then by value?
I tried this:

```
{
    "suggest": {
        "suggest-first" : {
            "prefix" : "Something1", 
            "completion" : { 
                "field" : "keySuggester",
                "fuzzy" : true,
                "size" : 20
            }
        },
        "suggest-second" : {
            "prefix" : "Something2", 
            "completion" : { 
                "field" : "valueSuggester",
                "fuzzy" : true,
                "size" : 20
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

But the result is two independed search results. And i want to first search the Key, and then by this key values, search for value for this key.